# Using Machine learning how to connect prediction back to existing information

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am fairly new to python so forgive me if this is a simple problem. What I am trying to do is make a simple bank classifier that takes in a list which includes categorized and uncategorized bank transactions. So they are objects which contain transactionId, Category and description. So far I can get my application to predict what the uncategorized transactions are based on the description but not connect it back to the existing data (put it back into the array of objects)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json 
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import itertools

allData = request.get_json()

list_from_json = allData['List']

classifiedList = []
unclassifiedList = []

for i in list_from_json:
    if not i["Category"]:
        unclassifiedList.append([i["TransactionId"], i["Category"], i["Description"]] )
    else:
        classifiedList.append([i["TransactionId"], i["Category"], i["Description"]])
       
print("this is the unclassified list size")
print(len(unclassifiedList))

df=pd.DataFrame(classifiedList, columns=["TransactionId" , "Category" , "Description"])

# convert the input text to something that sklearn can compute on using a TfidfVectorizer
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer()
x_train=tfidf.fit_transform(df.Description)

# we need to also encode the "target" as something the algorithm can handle (numbers)
le=LabelEncoder()
y_train=le.fit_transform(df.Category)

# here's the actual ML algorithm
classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)

# train the model on your historical data
classifier.fit(x_train.todense(), y_train)

gf=pd.DataFrame(unclassifiedList, columns=["TransactionId" , "Category" , "Description"])

# here's our "new" data that we want to get categories for, we need to treat it the same way
x_predict=tfidf.transform(gf.Description)

# do the magic prediction!
predicted=classifier.predict(x_predict.todense())
# predict() output is just a bunch of numbers, we need to turn it back into words
actual_answers=le.inverse_transform(predicted)

#Like I said this returns the categories but I want to connect it back to the overall list
print(actual_answers)

#jsonAnswer = json.dumps(actual_answers)
a = actual_answers.tolist()
b = json.dumps({"List": a})

return b
```

Comment: for help, give us the data you are using.  Can you paste the contents of `allData`?

Comment: `code`
 {"List":
  [{"TransactionId":"6979f8de-37e8-406f-b9de-ecc17778f18f","Category":"groceries","AccountType":"Chequing","Description":"CO-OP GROC","Amount":"-10.76","TransactionDate":"8/24/2020"},
  {"TransactionId":"4c097fe2-690c-4a2b-acfe-8a442afb6777","Category":"","AccountType":"Chequing","Description":"PAYROLL DEPOSIT","Amount":"10.57","TransactionDate":"8/31/2020"},
  {"TransactionId":"ceaef8bf-712c-4dba-9956-08feb1ece5c3","Category":"","AccountType":"Chequing","Description":"PAYROLL DEPOSIT","Amount":"10.25","TransactionDate":"8/31/2020"}]}
 `code`

Comment: I had to reduce it by quite a bit I have a lot of categorized data for the ML to find the pattern, provided is one sample categorized and one uncategorized.

Comment: Put the code in the question.  We should be able to run all the code in the question as-is, otherwise nobody will be able to help